# Locking the speed of the cpu on an android phone

Tags: battery-life, performance

The battery life of my cell phone lasts for about 6 hours. About 2 days ago I downloaded the app CPUControl to reduce the speed of my CPU. This resulted in more than 20 hours of battery life. However I changed the settings and I haven't been able to achieve the results I had before. I have a 4 X ARM Cortex-A7 CPU with a top speed of 1.3 GHz.

When I change the speed to 600 MHz, the change only lasts about 2 minutes ant then the processor goes up to 1 GHz draining my battery life very quickly.

You can't tell the difference between the processor running at 600 MHz or 1.3 GHz, either way it's fast enough.

What happened, how come I cant lock the processor speed anymore?

Comment: Which CPU governor are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of CPUControl's settings but you can try some other applications to lock the speed. You can try [KernelAduiter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grarak.kerneladiutor&hl=en) to perform this and many more operations.

You can change the CPU speed by specifying the minimum and the maximum and for best battery and if you're unable to do so, change the CPU governors.

1. If the CPU speed increases to 1.3GHz only for a few seconds randomly, set the governor to *Conservative*
2. If the CPU stays for long at 1.3GHz, check out which application is using the CPU so much.

2a. Open [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en)

- Gain root access using `su`
- Run `top` and let it display results on the screen
- Press `Volume Down + c` to terminate the command
- Scroll to the top and check out the process/app using the maximum CPU. If you find that process/app useless, terminate it

Comment: For some reason, the only governor that works is hotplug. All the others would work until the screen blacks out. So this solved the problem.